# Spring mvc 4.2.5 showing no class defenision found exception after configring spring data for mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am a new-bee in Spring MVC with mongo DB. I have created Spring MVC application with traditional DB (Postgresql-JDBC template) before. Since 1 week, I'm facing a problem in my project after configuring MongoDB beans.

I created a spring MVC application that was working fine. Now I need to keep my data to MongoDB (MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9),

So I downloaded related jars, So please check my dependencies version (I tried maven but that also showing error).

```
 mongodb-version - 3.2.9
 Spring mvc version - 4.2.5.RELEASE
 mongo-java-driver  - 3.4.1
 spring-data-commons -2.0.0.M1
 spring-data-mongodb -2.0.0.M1
 slf4j-log4j12-1.7.22.jar
 log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.jar
 Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost
 java 8
 Dynamic Web Module 3.1
```

IDE - Eclipse mars

I am keeping all jars in WEB-INF/lib folder
Here I would like to give my spring-dispatcher-servlet

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.classes.controller">
</context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017"/>
<mongo:db-factory dbname="dbfriendbook" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/view/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
</bean>

<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000" />
</beans:bean>

</beans>
```

And this is my applicationContext.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.classes.controller">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan> 
</beans>
```

and my web.xml as follows

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"
     version="3.0">
<display-name>RealWorldContest</display-name>
   <!-- <welcome-file-list>
           <welcome-file>main_home.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>-->

  <display-name>Real World Contest</display-name>
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
     </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>
         /
      </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     <listener>
      <listener- class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>

   </web-app>
```

I am getting a stack trace during initializing the server that is given below

```
 SEVERE: Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.MongoRepositoryConfigNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.MongoRepositoryConfigNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1406)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
... 36 more


 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.<clinit>(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:50)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.MongoRepositoryConfigNamespaceHandler.init(MongoRepositoryConfigNamespaceHandler.java:37)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:131)
... 43 more

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
... 46 more
```

I have found many questions related to this but everyone using the different version of spring mostly using Spring 3.x releases.

I have tried 3.x version but again I found jar version issue. I tried maven but that time servlet life cycle exception occurring in my project. I would like to use spring MVC 4.2.5 because I completed a project with psql as DB and SpringJdbcTemplate as the dependency before.I would be happier if I get a solution with Spring 4.2.5 version.

I would like to also know about LoggerFactory and its need in MongoDB spring project. If anyone got the problem please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are just into learning Spring Data MongoDB, I'd suggest using Spring boot. It's very simple to configure things without any of the above xml hassle. And, not sure why you aren't using maven for dependency management. If you wire dependencies via your own lib folder, there'll not be an end to it. So, my suggestion is to use maven.

Comment: @VishwasShashidhar I tried maven but after applying maven my server couldn't it was facing servlet life cycle exception. ok let me try one more time , and will you help me for adding correct dependencies.

Comment: Sure, give it a shot and let me know. If you are just trying to experiment, go through these links -> https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/creating-a-rest-api-with-spring-boot-and-mongodb/ and https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

Comment: can you try to add slf4j-api.jar ?

Comment: thank you.. @iMysak yeah it is because of lack of dependencies now am getting another error with mongoTemplate initialization. its interesting .. let me try spring boot as Vishwas Shashidhar mentioned.

Comment: agree, for learning and prototyping — using boot is preferable, this can save a lot of time for you.

Comment: So finally i solved the problem by using maven , Sorry @VishwasShashidhar i didnt use spring boot but swear that I will use spring boot soon :-).

Comment: Good for you :) but, try it, it's absolutely worth your time and more...And, this can help with all your project's dependencies -> http://start.spring.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this same problem before,will you please try with these maven dependencies

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
<version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yeah I think i solved the problem by using maven. Your answer is almost ok . Thank you @Asnad P